# List menu keep border on small size

Tags: css, flexbox

How to keep black border on the active element on small width resolutin 500px - 400px?
The only solution I found is to remove the align items but it doesn't look that good, other solution is to make it go outside of the view and make it scrollable but I don't know how to make that

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-item active">
          <a href="">test</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-item">
          <a href="">bigger text</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-item active">
          <a href="">even bigger text inside</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list-item">
          <a href="">text</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the css

```
.list-group{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #EEF7FF;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.list-item{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;

  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  @media (max-width: 767px){
    padding: 20px 20px;
  }
  @media (max-width: 575px){
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
  }

}

.list-item.active{
  border-bottom: 4px solid #000000;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}

.list-item:hover{
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #000000;

}

.list-item a:hover, .list-item a:active, .list-item a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}
```

[This](https://codepen.io/alexx295/pen/rNZemmL) is the link for codepen example

Comment: Use another media query on the active class.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't clear what's your problem. Can you explain more about what's your problem & your target?

Comment: Well I am trying to display on active element a black border bottom that is in the same line with the long blue border, on width smaller then 450px that border bottom for the active element is with 20px above the blue border, look on codepen with width 450px, and I want to make it responsive, cause I could put on smaller elements another class with margin-bottom: -20px, but I want to be responsive not hard coded
Hope this is more clear